# join 2 tables and display menu with only group name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
group
--id
--name
category
--id
--name
--group_id
```

and the query:

```sql
SELECT group.id AS gid, group.name AS gname, 
       category.id AS cid, category.name AS cname 
  FROM group join category 
    on group.id = category.group_id
```

and result for it is demonstrated as below:

```
gid--gname--cid--cname
1 ---abc----1----def
1 ---abc----2----ggg
2 ---ccc----3----eee
2 ---ccc----4----fff
```

I want to show a menu like this:

```
abc
--def
--ggg
ccc
--eee
--fff
```

I can't show menu as above if I use that query (infact, I can but it's hard). 
What query or a way can help me do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of presentation, but you may find it handy to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in situation like this to pack categories per group

```sql
SELECT g.id gid, g.name gname, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.id, '|', c.name) ORDER BY c.id) categories
  FROM `group` g JOIN category c 
    ON g.id = c.group_id
 GROUP BY g.id, g.name
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9856/4)** demo

and then easily `explode()` categories column in php while you iterate over the resultset

Just to give you an idea how php part might look like using `PDO`

```php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$sql = "SELECT g.id gid, g.name gname, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.id, '|', c.name) ORDER BY c.id) categories
  FROM `group` g JOIN category c 
    ON g.id = c.group_id
 GROUP BY g.id, g.name";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query = null;
$db = null;

echo '<ul>';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<li>' . $row['gid'] . '-' . $row['gname'];
    $categories = explode(',', $row['categories']);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        list($cid, $cname) = explode('|', $category);
        echo '<li>' . $cid . '-' .$cname . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Output:

- 1-abc

  - 1-def
  - 2-ggg
- 2-ccc

  - 3-eee
  - 4-fff

Answer (score 1):

basically you have to loop for each group and printing all category belong to that group.
in php u can do this:

```
while( $group = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM group") ) ){
    echo $group[1];
    while( $category = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT id, name from category where group_id =" . $group[0] ) ) ){
        echo $category[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: don't tell people to use the `mysql_*` commands. They are deprecated and should not be used any longer. Teach people to use either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
array('gid'=>1, 'gname'=>'abc', 'cid'=>1, 'cname'=>'def'),
array('gid'=>1, 'gname'=>'abc', 'cid'=>2, 'cname'=>'ggg'),
array('gid'=>2, 'gname'=>'ccc', 'cid'=>3, 'cname'=>'eee'),
array('gid'=>2, 'gname'=>'ccc', 'cid'=>4, 'cname'=>'fff'),
);

$res = array();



    foreach($arr as $ar){
              if(empty($res[$ar['gid']])){
                 $res[$ar['gid']] = array(
                     'gid'=>$ar['gid'],
                     'gname'=>$ar['gname'],

                 );
              }              
                $res[$ar['gid']]['category'][] = array('cid'=>$ar['cid'],'cname'=>$ar['cname']);


      }
       print_r($res);
```

Comment: _Try This_ (code-only) answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and future researchers.  Always provide an explanation with your snippets.  It's never too late to edit an answer.  Doing so role models better behavior for new users who may think that it is okay to post code-only answers.